# 'Loss not found' error when compiling model

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am making a program for classifying hand-written digits, but building the model gives me the following error

```
ValueError: No loss found. You may have forgotten to provide a `loss` argument in 
the `compile()` method
```

the code for the model is as follows

```py
# making the model

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()

model.add(tf.keras.Input(28*28))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation = 'softmax'))

model.compile(
    optimizer='adam',
    loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
    metrics=['accuracy']
)
print(model.summary())
```

I have tried with other losses but still the same error persists.

The libraries that I used are as follows

```py
# importing important libraries

import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

Comment: Try `tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy` instead.

Comment: Please include explicitly your *imports*; see how to create a [mre].